# Using EEPROM in STM32f10x

Tags: stm32, keil, flash-memory, eeprom

I'm using STM32f103 and in my program, I need to save some bytes in the internal flash memory. But as far as I know, I have to erase a whole page to write in it, which will take time.
This delay causes my display to blink.
Can anybody help me to save my data without consuming so much time?

Here is a list that may help:

1- MCU: STM32f103

2- IDE: Keil vision

3- using HAL driver provided by STM32CubeMx

4- sample data for saving in Flash: {0x53, 0xa0, 0x01, 0x54}

In the link below, you can find the code that I'm using.

[FLASH_PAGE for Keil](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbVR0dmZnbUZFazVGdnc5djJHbDExWlZuNkZrd3xBQ3Jtc0tsb0o0YTFYZVBoRkRJdW5JRnFSQjlJbGFvbGl3LVdXS2k1WGZ6UFdMY1lSOFh1aUZKYm5FQllxZTB5NUc3NFZGNVVYVEc5UVJESi1yUWVhVG1iaURkVV9DdnM0VFBuNDB3cFJpVzM0RC1NZTd2dU9fMA&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcontrollerstech.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2020%2F11%2FFLASH_PAGE_KeilFiles.zip&v=BKgh896Bj8Q&html_redirect=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provide doesn't seem to be implemented well. It basically does 2 things each time you initiate a write operation:

1. Erase the page (this is the part that takes time)
2. Start form the given pointer, write until it hits a zero.

This is a very ineffective way of using the flash.

Probably the simplest and the most well-known way is to use the method described in ST's [AN2594](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-stm32010.html), although it has some limitations.

Still, at some point a page erase will be necessary regardless the method you use and there is no way to avoid some delay, unless your uC supports dual flash banks (STM32F103 don't have this feature). You need to plan the timing of flash writes and display refresh accordingly. If you need periodic writes to the flash, there is probably some high level error in your design.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I used another library that STM itself presented. I had to include "eeprom.h" into your project and then add "eeprom.c" to it. You can easily find these files on the Internet.